# Update Scope by selecting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have two tables that I want to filter by either using an individual select dropdown in the table row or by selecting multiple checkboxes and bulk updating the scope.

A user should be able to check the records, select the top dropdown status, and then the scope gets updated. If the status is greater than or equal to 1 it goes in one table, if less then it goes in the other table.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/hxz06sd7/

How can I use the checkboxes to update the checked values based upon selected value?

The select

```
 <select ng-options="item.value as item.displayName for item in StatusDropDown" ng-model="person.status" ng-change="updateSelected()"></select>
```

updatedSelected should take the checked rows and filter:

```
$scope.updateSelected = function(statusarg){
            //how to set status for selected and update tables

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't have put the fiddle in the comment. :) Now that you got most part of your original question figured. Your question originally was too broad. I had placed ng-model in those checkboxes, On click of save just filter persons to get the checked ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associate ng-model (`person.selected`) to the checkboxes and on-change, filter them out based on the selected property, and apply the `value` to them.

```
$scope.updateSelected = function (statusarg) {
    //how to set status for selected and update tables
    angular.forEach($scope.people, function(person){
        person.selected && (person.status = statusarg);
    });
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totgxvst/)**

Earlier issues with your code was that: You should not use `track by` with `select as` syntax they are not meant to work together. You would rarely need to use track by with ng-options. [Read this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/directive/select#-select-as-and-track-by-) for more details.